How to write custom plugin for flink
I try to write my custom flink plugin.
My simple example. I added in META-INF/services file:
org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.JobStatusListener

whitch contains my class name:
com.example.flink.JobStatusPrinter


public class JobStatusPrinter implements JobStatusListener {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobStatusPrinter.class);

  public void open(Configuration configuration) {
    LOG.info("The JobStatusListenerPluginExample is opened using config: {}", configuration.toMap());
  }

  public void close() {
    LOG.info("The JobStatusListenerPluginExample is closed");
  }

  public void jobStatusChanges(JobID jobID, JobStatus jobStatus, long timestamp) {
    LOG.info("The status of the job {} is changed to {}", jobID, jobStatus);
  }
}

In logs I see, that my plugin was loaded:
o.a.f.c.plugin.DefaultPluginManager - Plugin loader with ID not found, creating it: flink-plugin

But, It not working. I expected that when I change the job status, I would see my message in the log.
What am I doing wrong, how do I get the plugin to initialize and work?
